# Characters not saving correctly in database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am not sure if this is because of jquery, mysql or php

I have a basic AJAX call:

```
$(document).on("click", "#save-edit", function(){
    var id = $(this).closest("div.answer-section").attr("data-id");
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        data: {
            id: id,
            answer: $("#edit-box").val()
        },
        url: "/process/edit",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            // display the data
        }
    });
});
```

and a basic SQL query:

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare("update answers set answer = :answer where answer_id = :aid");
$sql->bindParam("answer", $_POST["answer"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam("aid", $_POST["id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->execute();
```

The problem I am having is, it saves characters like this: `é é` in the database as this `Ã© Ã©` then displays `Ã© Ã©` on the page, so what is causing this, the JQuery, or the MySQL or the PHP? How can I fix it?

Comment: Hard to say from the given data. Do you have your page encoding and database-connection and database-column encoding right? I prefer to set everything to `utf-8` or `utf8_unicode`.

Comment: http://kunststube.net/encoding/

Comment: @Simon all tables Collation is set to `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: @RyanNaddy If the db-connection and the web-pages encoding is also set to utf-8 there should not be a problem. Did you also check if the browser gets the right code-page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the answer, every thing is fine, just needed to add this to the HTML header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```